# getting value of listview having recylerview

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have made a vertical listview of in which i have added horizontal recylerview in each item of listview, i am able to get the the details of recylerview but i dont know how to get the value of listview in which i clicked the particular items of recylerview. Help me out here and i have also pasted my snap of layout- [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eagy.png)

**ListAdapter:**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private Context context;
    private String[] names={"Lesson 1: Intro","Lesson 2: Addition","Lesson 3: Subtraction","Lesson 4: Multiplication","Lesson 5: Geometry","Lesson 6: Shapes","Lesson 7: Quad","Lesson 8: Fun","Lesson 9: Problems-1","Lesson 10: Problems-2"};
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    LessonVideoAdapter recyclerAdapter;

    public ListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        recyclerAdapter=new LessonVideoAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view1=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.abc_lesson_name,null,false);

         TextView tittle=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.lesson_name);
         tittle.setText(names[i]);

        RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view1.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewChapters);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        return view1;

        }
}
```

Recycler Adapter:

```
public class LessonVideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LessonVideoAdapter.LessonDataHolder> {

    private List<VideoList> slipList;


    public LessonVideoAdapter() {
        slipList = new ArrayList<>();
        slipList.add(new VideoList("Chapter 1", R.drawable.demo_one));
        slipList.add(new VideoList("Chapter 2", R.drawable.demo_two));
        slipList.add(new VideoList("Chapter 3", R.drawable.demo_one));
        slipList.add(new VideoList("Chapter 4", R.drawable.demo_two))
    }

    @Override
    public LessonDataHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.abc_card_view_video, parent, false);

        return new LessonDataHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LessonDataHolder holder, int position) {

        VideoList s = slipList.get(position);
        holder.bindSlip(s);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return slipList.size();
    }


    class LessonDataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


        private TextView nameOfSlip;
        private ImageView slipImage;
        private Context context;


        public LessonDataHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            context = itemView.getContext();
            nameOfSlip = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.demoText);
            slipImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDemoVideo);

            slipImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void bindSlip(VideoList videoList) {
            nameOfSlip.setText(videoList.stringSlipName);
            slipImage.setImageResource(videoList.stringImage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {


            if (view.getId() == slipImage.getId()) {

//                String s = String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()+1);
                String s1 = ((nameOfSlip).getText().toString());

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.abc_dialog_option_chapter);
                dialog.setTitle("What Do You Want?");

                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogLessonName);
                text.setText("Lesson Name");

                TextView text1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogChapterName);
                text1.setText(s1);

                Button b1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogPlayVideo);
                b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YouTubePlayerActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("demoVideo", "oYaR9wyLiWs");
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                Button b2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogPlayQuiz);
                b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, QuizActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                Button b3 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogPlayCrossword);
                b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CrosswordActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

            }
        }
    }
}

class VideoList {
    public String stringSlipName;
    public int stringImage;

    public VideoList(String stringSlipName, int stringImage) {
        this.stringImage = stringImage;
        this.stringSlipName = stringSlipName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to use this sample code to get `ListView` item clicked

```
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```